# How can do multiple modal with tailwind element's component

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to do authentication modals when I am login modal and click "create account" On this modal I need to hide the login modal and open the register modal standard process should be done. I use tailwind element's modal and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a wrapper element around the "create account" button element. This then means you can have one element dismiss the current modal, and the other to show the new modal:

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/tw-elements.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<button type="button" data-te-toggle="modal" data-te-target="#login" class="rounded px-2 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-primary">
  Login
</button>

<div
  data-te-modal-init
  class="fixed z-[1055] top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 z-10 hidden"
  id="login"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div data-te-modal-dialog-ref class="bg-white p-5 w-max mx-auto">
    <div data-te-modal-dismiss>
      <button type="button" data-te-toggle="modal" data-te-target="#create" class="rounded bg-secondary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-white">
        Create account
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div
  data-te-modal-init
  class="fixed z-[1055] top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 z-10 hidden"
  id="create"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div data-te-modal-dialog-ref class="bg-white p-5 w-max mx-auto">
      <button type="button" class="rounded bg-primary px-6 pb-2 pt-2.5 text-white" data-te-modal-dismiss>
        Foo
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"></script>
```